# Sequential read of a mainframe dataset using Java program

Tags: java, mainframe

I am trying to read a mainframe sequential dataset using a Java program.

My Java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.ibm.recordio.*;

public class Sequential {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                try {
                    IRecordFile file = RecordFile.getInstanceOf("//" + args[0]);
                    IRandomAccessRecordFile randomFile = RandomAccessRecordFile.getInstanceOf(file, IConstants.JRIO_READ_MODE);
                    readSequentially(randomFile);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(8);
                }
            }

            // Reads the randomly accessible file sequentially.
            private static void readSequentially(IRandomAccessRecordFile randomFile) throws IOException {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[randomFile.getRecordLength()];
                // Position at the beginning of the file.
                randomFile.positionFirst();
                while (randomFile.read(buffer) != -1) {
                    // Read bytes into buffer. Do something...
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer));
                }
            }


}
```

I tried to compile this code using the below JCL.

```
//DMKSAMP1 JOB ('3000-000000-00-Z-00000000000'),
//            'P19314881-090817-0-S',REGION=0M,
//            CLASS=G,MSGCLASS=H,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
/*JOBPARM LINECT=0,ROOM=ZZZZ
/*ROUTE PRINT PARSIP0
//BPXBATCH EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,
//         PARM='SH javac /u/dmksn/Sequential.java',
//         REGION=0M
//STDOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*
//STDERR   DD   SYSOUT=*
//STDENV DD DUMMY
```

I got an error - `package com.ibm.recordio does not exist`. What do I need to do to successfully compile the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned JRIO has been deprecated and thank goodness because it was a lousy API! For reading sequential data sets you should definitely use the [`JZOS RecordReader`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.71.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/RecordReader.html) class. It uses BSAM overlapping I/O and is significantly faster than regular `ZFile` which is a simple JNI wrapper over C stdio.

```java
 String ddname = ZFile.allocDummyDDName();
 String cmd = "alloc fi("+ddname+") da(HLQ.MYDATA) reuse shr msg(2)";
 ZFile.bpxwdyn(cmd);
 RecordReader reader = null;
 try {
   reader = RecordReader.newReaderForDD(ddname);
   byte[] recordBuf = new byte[reader.getLrecl()];
   while ((bytesRead = reader.read(recordBuf)) >= 0) {
     ...
   }
 } finally {
   if (reader != null) {
     try {
       reader.close(); 
     } catch (ZFileException zfe) {
       zfe.printStackTrace();  // but continue
     } 
   }
   try {
     ZFile.bpxwdyn("free fi(" + ddname + ") msg(2)");
   } catch (RcException rce) {
     rce.printStackTrace();  // but continue
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

com.ibm.recordio was part of IBM Java Record I/O (JRIO) and was deprecated as of IBM Java SDK 6.0.1 some ten years ago as of this writing.

[IBM recommends](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/7?topic=components-java-record-io-jrio) migrating to the IBM JZOS toolkit.  This is something your z/OS Systems Programmer would install.